# How can I mark VM as staging or development environment machine

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, web-deployment, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a few number of VMs where I deploy my `ASP.Net Core` application.

It has environment based `appsettings.json` file for app configuration.

- appsettings.Development.json
- appsettings.Staging.json
- appsettings.Test.json
- appsettings.Production.json

But I have no clue how can I mark/configure the VMs environment Like

- VM #1 = Development
- VM #2 = Staging
- VM #3 = Production

I have ***Windows Server 2012 R2*** as VM machines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to "Development", "Staging", or "Production".

Comment: Correct. That I can do using Visual Studio. how can I configure without it as I don't & won't have VS on any of the VMs

Comment: You don't do it using Visual Studio. You set the environment variable using Control Panel... System... Advanced system settings... Environment Variables. If there's already an ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable defined, edit it to have the value you want. If not, add the variable.